# ActiveModel::MissingAttributeError: thrown in tests but not console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am new to Rails, and I am trying to set up a very simple model. There are three model classes: Solution, Pro, and Con. Pros and Cons are children of solutions like so:

```
class Solution < ActiveRecord::Base
  include BasicValidations
  has_many :pros
  has_many :cons
end
```

and

```
class Con < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :solution
end

class Pro < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :solution
end
```

But, if I try to run a test as follows:

```
def setup
  @test_class = Solution
  @solution = FactoryGirl.create(:solution)
end

test "Solutions can take pros" do
  c = @solution.pros.create(description: "pros")
  assert_includes(@solution.pros, c,"Could not add pro to solution") 
end
```

I get the following error:

```
2) Error:
  SolutionTest#test_Solutions_can_take_pros:
  ActiveRecord::UnknownAttributeError: unknown attribute 'solution_id' for   Pro.
    test/models/solution_test.rb:12:in `block in <class:SolutionTest>'
```

...but only some of the time, and the same test if carried out manually in rails console works!

Here's the DB migration:

```
class AddProsAndConsToSolution < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    change_table :pros do |t|
      t.belongs_to :solution, index: true
    end

    change_table :cons do |t|
      t.belongs_to :solution, index: true
    end
  end  
end
```

...and the schema:

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20150323133049) do

  create_table "cons", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.string   "description", limit: 255
    t.integer  "solution_id"
  end

  add_index "cons", ["solution_id"], name: "index_cons_on_solution_id"

  create_table "pros", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "description", limit: 255
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.integer  "solution_id"
  end

  add_index "pros", ["solution_id"], name: "index_pros_on_solution_id"

  create_table "solutions", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "description", limit: 255
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end
end
```

I'm running Rails 4.2.1.

Any thoughts? It seems so straightforward that I must have missed something obvious, but the fact that it works occasionally in testing and in the console confuses me.

Comment: try `rake db:reset RAILS_ENV=test`

Comment: Thank you! Yes, that worked. If you put it as an answer I'll mark it as such

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `rake db:reset RAILS_ENV=test`, it will drop your existing database (`rake db:drop`), create it anew (`rake db:create`), load the schema retrieved from your current development db condition (`rake db:schema:load`), and seed the database (`rake db:seed`), all only within your `test` database configuration, determined in **config/database.yml** file and set by setting `RAILS_ENV` global variable to `test`.

> And the same test if carried out manually in rails console works

It worked because tests are run in **test** RAILS_ENV and your console was in **development** RAILS_ENV.
You could access test environment's console by typing: `rails console test`.

Answer (score 0):

Did you finish migrating your test db?

`rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=test`

Comment: Yes I did, it turns out I needed to run rake db:reset